# GeoQuiz Android App does not run

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

My code isn't running on my phone. I get the following error.

```
Error: adev_set_parameters: ERROR: set param called even when stream out is null

Error: W/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiV02::injectPosition(double, double, float):496]: error! status= eLOC_CLIENT_FAILURE_INVLAID_PARAMETER, inject_pos_ind.status = eQMI_LOC_SUCCESS_V02
```

I am using eclipse and android 4.2 moto x.
I am trying to make a basic quiz game that asks the user to select true or false. Upon answering, the result should be displayed on screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YIr1.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK4hx.png

Comment: Strings BTW
http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIOgf.png

Comment: can you post your logcat completely!

Comment: Which format? Debug, error, verbose etc.

Comment: post verbose please, from beginning of `fatal error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah i had the same issue, you have to reinstall eclipse and it should work